# Copying data from External hard disk to thumb drive

Tags: hard-drive, usb-drive

I tried copying some movies from my HDD (of 1 TB) to my pendrive so I could go play it somewhere else. The problem is that it starts the copy file operation , and after nearing completion, it just stops there, and it doesn't respond. I tried it for every file and with two pendrive just to make sure there is nothing wrong with the file.
What is happening?

Comment: Have you tried copying from terminal?

Comment: No I haven't. But how would it make any difference? Is there a possibility that the gui would slow or hamper the process?

Comment: Yes it's slow, at least the times I've tried.  Try it from terminal, and let us know.

Comment: Sure. I'll do that and post results here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is very simple: Ubuntu is using the cache (basically your RAM) to copy and *while the file is being copied to the cache*, it starts emptying the cache to the USB.  When it arrives at the end, only the cache needs emptying, so it is just waiting for the USB stick to catch up.

This is a *feature* of the kind of USB stick you buy: [MLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell) USB sticks have this much more pronounced then Single Level Cell (SLC) ones.  However, SLC USB sticks are about 3-4 times more expensive then SLC ones, so normally they're not on display in stores and you have to order them.  The advantage is they're 4-8 times as fast and last 4-8 times as long as SLC ones, so in the end you win twice by only buying MLC drives (or just waiting for the SLC to finish!)  **;-)**

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. I am between exams :(
So is there a fix?

Comment: Marking it as closed. Fixed itself. Weird.

Comment: If you copy files within the cache, it'll go fast.  If you go outside of your cache, it'll go slow... so there is no real "fix" except a faster USB stick... :(